# How to use last element of a list in for loop?

Tags: python, list, element

I want to use the last element of a list in a for loop to generate new element. Here is a toy example of my problem:

```
  a = [1]
  a += [a[-1]+i for i in range(10)]
```

but it only consider 1 as last element and does not go through for loop to find the new last element. Could you please tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I run the code and got the following answer:

```
In [2]: a = [1]

In [3]:  a += [a[-1]+i for i in range(1,10)]

In [4]: a
Out[4]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: No, for example the 4th element should be 4 not 3.

Comment: It's because  the range function generates 0 to 9,  so if you start from
 a += [a[-1]+i for i in range(1,10)] , you will get the output [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = [1]
for i in range(10):
  a.append(a[-1]+i)
print(a)
```

Using list comprehension won't take the new last value of the array on each new iteration, but using a normal `for` loop will.

Comment: I just didn't want to have for loop like this to run the code faster.

Comment: I don't think this is any slower than list comprehension. What you are doing above is also a loop, just within a list comprehension.